# Subprocess Command Output?

Tags: python, string, shell

I have been trying for hours to get the output of a shell command as a string. I have tried both `subprocess` and `os`, neither of which have worked, and within `subprocess` I have tried `check_output()`, `getoutput()`, `Popen()`, `communicate()`, and everything else I've been able to find on this site and many others.

Sometimes I've had errors such as `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` though I have been able to fix these relatively swiftly, however when the code does actually work, and I try to print the output of the command, either it returns nothing (as in, it prints blank space), or it prints `(b'', b'')` or `(b'', None)`.

`decode()` doesn't work, `encoding` doesn't change anything and I even tried:

```
subpr = str(process)
```

which, of course, did nothing.

How do you get the output of a shell command, as a string?

Other attempts:

```
subpr = (Popen(commandRun,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE,universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0])

process = subprocess.getoutput(commandRun)

process = subprocess.check_output(commandRun,shell=True)

process = subprocess.check_output(commandRun,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)

process = Popen(commandRun,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
subpr = process.communicate()[0]

output = Popen(commandRun,shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
subpr = output.communicate()
```

Imported:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```

There is not much more code to add. I haven't written anything regarding subprocess other than that one broken line.

Comment: Would you please add some more code? There is probably something wrong in your invocation of `subprocess`.

Comment: This line `subpr = (subprocess.Popen(commandRun,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0])` works too. Are you sure there is nothing wrong with the process you are running?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I don't know, it's possible. The `commandRun` variable is a combination of two commands, and I may have strung them together incorrectly. The first part is setting the file path to a raw path on my disk, then the second part is the actual command. The command doesn't work without the file path.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @SAIJAL Python 3.9.5

Comment: @dan Yes, Windows 10

Comment: @MauriceMeyer "1"

Comment: The return code indicates that the command failed. If you are trying to run Unix commands on Windows, that won't work out of the box; install the required tools from a third party such as Cygwin, or run the code on a Unix-like platform instead (you will be happy to leave Windows behind for many other reasons too anyway).

Comment: Also, you can't combine two commands in one subprocess unless you specify `shell=True` (in which case `commandRun` should be a string, not a list).

Comment: @tripleee You are right, it's an issue with the command, though I have tried `shell=True` and `commandRun` has been a string from the start

Comment: As long as you steadfastly refuse to show us the actual commands, we can only endlessly speculate. If the duplicate doesn't solve your problem, probably look at related questions; if you still can't find one which covers your specific problem, please [edit] to provide an actual [mre] and we can discuss reopening.

Comment: Check out this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output and word search it for `Windows` also.

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to use these?

I have the following code that works, redirecting STDERR to STDOUT, because I wanted to have them merged:

```py
import subprocess
args = ["whoami"]
run = subprocess.run(args, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(run.stdout)
```

If you want to pipe processes together, the best way is probably to put the popes in arguments of `Popen`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-command-substitution

```py
p1 = Popen(["dmesg"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "hda"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()  # Allow p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits.
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: This prints nothing for me. I'm trying to use it to run a command in shell, then take the output of said command and write it to a file (while also printing it).

Comment: This prints nothing with `whoami`? Or with another command?

Comment: `whoami` works, so I think you are correct that it is something to do with my command

Comment: Are you using the correct separators for the command? | pipes (pipelines) the standard output (stdout) of one command into the standard input of another one. Note that stderr still goes into its default destination, whatever that happens to be. && executes the right-hand command of && only if the previous one succeeded.

Comment: @SAIJAL I think it is likely something to do with the file path - the first half of the command is setting the path of the command

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the path"? If you need a specific working directory you can pass it as `cwd=...`

Comment: Running `grep` in a subprocess is inelegant and wasteful, though; Python can perfectly well extract the lines which contain a particular string or match a particular regex.

Comment: This is an example from the python docs... It's not production code...